# Managing session temporarily in ibm mobilefirst?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i have to develop a multipage application that includes invocation of several  web services.

My first page has a login page. based on the user input i have to traverse to next page while calling the next web service simultaneously. so obviously this all depends on the login page information that has the userid and password and the response from the web service such as personId etc.

i need to store this information temporarily for a particular session but... how to do this?

Comment: What does this has to do with sessions or with being "simultaneous", if it depends on the previous request? That by definition means it is not simultaneous.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of page:

There are the UI states as seen by the user. Your Login page and your Next page are examples of these. From the user's perspective they see a succession of pages.

However you are writing an App, a single controlling thing that is in charge of all those "UI pages". I suppose that you are using MobileFirst to create a hybrid application that is effectively executing in a browser. From that browser's perspective you have a single HTML page. This is important, MobileFirst only works with single-page applications.

Now the browser loads the HTML and JavaScript for your single application page and that JavaScript stays resident as the user moves between the different "UI Pages", so the JavaScript can have variables for keeping the state you are asking about. The actual UI navigation from "page" to "page" is usually done by hiding and revealing DIVs.

Hence your WebService call results will be delivered (asynchronously) to some JavaScript function you define, and in the meantime your code can hide the login page and reveal the next page as required. The login data being held in JavaScript variabes.

All of this is simplified by using a framework such as AngularJS which abstracts the messy details of hiding and revealing and dealing with asynch delivery.